# Generalized Method for Constrained Extrema on non-compact set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, compactness

Let $M:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2\geq36\}$ and $f: \mathbb R^{3} \to \mathbb R, f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{6}$

Find the Extrema and their type.

**Ideas:** Firstly define $h: \mathbb R^{3} \to \mathbb R$ as $h(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-36$

We know that $M$ is not sequentially compact, using a sequence $(k+6,0,0)_{k\in \mathbb N}$ and therefore it is not compact.

Until now, I have only done constrained extrema on compact sets where we could simply find the critical points and then (based on the fact that $M$ is compact) we would know that there exists a global maximum and minimum, and then simply evaluate.

Nonetheless, in this case we know that $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to\infty}f(x,y,z)=+\infty$ and thus $f|_{M}$ has a lower bound. How can we know, however, that $f|_{M}$ "takes on" a minimum.

**Question**: Is there a generalized way to go about finding Extrema on non-compact sets? Do I still need to find the critical points and evaluate them or what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, $\lim_{\|(x,y,z)\|\to\infty}f(x,y,z)=+\infty$ and therefore the function $f$ cannot have a global maximum. Besides, $f$ has no critical points in $M$. Therefore, $f$ has a minimum, which must be located at the boundary of $M$.

Comment: If $f$ had critical points in $M$, would I have to compare the critical points to the boundary of $M$ ? Or simply, use the critical points. I am generally confused about when we should consider boundary points and when we can just focus on critical points.

Comment: Yes, you would have to consider the boundary too.

Comment: Of course. It may happen that the global maximum or the global minimum is located there.

Comment: Wait, let me rephrase that: Define $M:= \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^{3}|x^2+y^2+z^2=36\}$  then I would **ONLY** work out the critical points on $M$, right? Seeing as though there is no need to evaluate the "end points" because there would not be any.

Comment: No. You must also see how $f$ behaves at the boundary of $M$.

Comment: You said something different here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2837495/512018

Comment: In that answer, I was talking about a function whose domain is a level curve. That's not the case here.

Comment: But so if I define $M:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^{3}|x^2+y^2+z^2=36\}$ why would I still have to evaluate the "end points" of $M$. I mean there aren't any end points in this case. Wouldn't $M$ be the level curve you're talking about??

Comment: You can't redefine $M$. You have to study the critical points of $f$ located at the interior of $M$ and also to study the behaviour of $f$ at $\partial M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,x^2+y^2+z^2=36\}$.

Comment: I do not think you understood what I mean: I am saying if we were to create a new question (forgetting the **old** constraint) with a new constraint $G$ where $G=\partial M$ then we can simply evaluate the critical points on $G$, right?

Comment: No. Since $\partial M$ is not an open set, that method doesn't work. What we should do is to use the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Yes, using langrange multipliers to get our critical points on $G$

Comment: For me, critical points are thos at which the gradient is $0$. I see now that you use that expression in a different sense. You are right, then.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413768/how-to-use-lagrange-multipliers-when-the-constraint-surface-has-a-boundary?rq=1 This is a useful example where the level curve does have a boundary.